# POP3 access to Gmail account will no longer be possible

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, proxy, gmail

Google will no longer support the use of third-party apps or devices which ask to sign in to the Google account using only the username and password. Thus, the POP3 access to my Gmail account will no longer work with my older version of Outlook. Therefore I'm looking for a solution.
I had a look at the 'OAuth2 Proxy' from GitHub (https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy). But I'm not sure if I can continue to use my older version of Outlook to retrieve my emails via POP3 from my Gmail account with this proxy.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
Michi

PS: I've a Windows server where I could install this proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to disable the 'Less Secure App Access' feature, enable the '2-Step Verification' feature and then set an 'App Password' which can be used as the password in Outlook. This way you can continue to use your older version of Outlook.

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, Outlook 2016 or earlier has less secure access to Gmail account. I'm afraid if we want to continue using outlook, we need to upgrade to Outlook 2019 or newer.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that with newer Outlook versions the access is still possible. But that's not the topic here, but if there's a way to get the emails using POP3 even with older Outlook versions. My hope is that this is possible with a proxy (e.g. 'OAuth2 Proxy' from GitHub), so that my older Outlook can connect to this proxy and this proxy then does the POP3 authentication to my Gmail account. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. But you can set an 'App Password' on Gmail so you can still access your emails with your older version of Outlook.

Comment: Will gmail access using pop3 with Outlook 2019 or newer possible? It's not clear from the text above if it's implied that even when upgrading to Outlook 2019 or newer, one would also need to switch to imap or what not.

Answer (score 0):

> Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Ditch the "older version of outlook" (Hard to believe they don't support IMAP and SSL though)
or better:
Ditch the data-harvesting behemoth that is google.