# Gmail can no longer connect to Outlook account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

My problem is that I'm trying to use Gmail to send/receive Outlook, and since last week that has completely broken. The connection broke and I keep getting this error in the settings for the account in Gmail:

> Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
>
> Server returned error: "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad
> password."

All of the info I can find info about setting up 2FA if I want to use Outlook to send/receive gmail. But I need to do it the other way around - use Gmail to send/receive Outlook.

Any ideas..??!

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1721559/pop3-access-to-gmail-account-will-no-longer-be-possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POP3 access to Gmail account will no longer be possible](https://superuser.com/questions/1721559/pop3-access-to-gmail-account-will-no-longer-be-possible)

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Gmail has announced that "To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password". Affected by this, please try the following steps mentioned in this [thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/883205/login-rejected-on-gmail.html?childToView=884013#answer-884013:%7E:text=2.Enable,App%20Passwords.) to solve the problem:

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: No, that is specifically the reverse of what OP is trying to do. I know this because I'm trying to do the same. I.e. use GMail to access an outlook POP3 email account. Your answer, and all the comments linking to other threads are about using Outlook to access a Gmail account.