# Unable to connect Gmail to Outlook pst file using pop3

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook

My Outlook stopped connecting to Gmail using pop3.

I'm using Outlook 2016.

This is after the unwanted Gmail security change...

I really could use a solve here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POP3 access to Gmail account will no longer be possible](https://superuser.com/questions/1721559/pop3-access-to-gmail-account-will-no-longer-be-possible)